# Is there a reproducible way of making a table of means from an existing table

Tags: r, mean

I am a beginner at R so please bear with me.

A toy-example of my problem would be somewhat like this -

| Fruits | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1_Fruit_A | 18 |
| 2_Fruit_A | 20 |
| 3_Fruit_A | 24 |
| 1_Fruit_B | 50 |
| 2_Fruit_B | 63 |
| 3_Fruit_B | 45 |
| 1_Fruit_C | 71 |
| 2_Fruit_C | 75 |
| 3_Fruit_C | 72 |

And from this table, I wish to create another table wherein I store data somewhat like this -

| Fruits | Means | Standard Deviation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit A - Average | 20.67 | 3 |
| Fruit B - Average | 52.67 | 2 |
| Fruit C - Average | 72.67 | 4 |

I need to write a reproducible code which I can use for say even coloured balls or flowers instead of fruits, but always a mean of triplicates which needs to be stored on another table with one column renamed and one column of means, I will then use ggplot to plot the resultant table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In base R, you can use the substr() function to extract the group name (Fruit A, Fruit B...), and calculate group mean using the aggregate() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar to @Ronak Shah's solution, but here I include a reproducible data and customized text manipulation on `Fruits` column, based on your updated data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(Fruits = 
                   c("1_Fruit_A",   
                     "2_Fruit_A",   
                     "3_Fruit_A",   
                     "1_Fruit_B",   
                     "2_Fruit_B",   
                     "3_Fruit_B",   
                     "1_Fruit_C",   
                     "2_Fruit_C", 
                     "3_Fruit_C"), 
                  Number = c(18, 20, 24, 50, 63, 45, 71, 75, 72))


mydf$Fruits <- mydf %>% 
  pull(Fruits) %>% 
  gsub("^[[:digit:]]+[_]", "", .) %>% 
  gsub("[_]", " ", .) %>% paste0(" - Average")

# Intermediate result
mydf
#              Fruits Number
# 1 Fruit A - Average     18
# 2 Fruit A - Average     20
# 3 Fruit A - Average     24
# 4 Fruit B - Average     50
# 5 Fruit B - Average     63
# 6 Fruit B - Average     45
# 7 Fruit C - Average     71
# 8 Fruit C - Average     75
# 9 Fruit C - Average     72


newdf <- mydf %>% group_by(Fruits) %>% summarise(Means = mean(Number), 
                                        `Standard Deviation` =  sd(Number))

# Final result

newdf
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#    Fruits            Means  `Standard Deviation`
#     <chr>             <dbl>                <dbl>
# 1 Fruit A - Average  20.7                 3.06
# 2 Fruit B - Average  52.7                 9.29
# 3 Fruit C - Average  72.7                 2.08
```

I think this code serves your purpose, but I strongly recommend to remove the words `Average` in `Fruits` column because it is misleading. It implies that the values in `Mean` column is not the mean of values of each group, but instead the mean of the average of the values of each group.

Comment: Hey, I just updated the question to better reflect my problem with using ```str_replace``` as well as my requirement for the standard deviation. Could you modify your code to match the newer requirements? Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the common value from `Fruits` column and use it as group and then take average value in each group.

For your example, you can drop everything after a `-`.

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Fruits = sub('\\s-.*', '', Fruits)) %>%
  summarise(Number = mean(Number), .groups = 'drop')

#   Fruits   Number
#1 Fruit A 20.66667
#2 Fruit B 52.66667
#3 Fruit C 72.66667
```

In base R,

```
aggregate(Number~Fruits, transform(df, Fruits = sub('\\s-.*', '', Fruits)), mean)
```

Comment: Hey, I just updated the question to better reflect my problem with using ```sub()``` as well as my requirement for the standard deviation. Could you modify your code to match the newer requirements? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

# create a new column which includes common string to aggregate upon

setDT(dfs)[,':='(
  aggstr = substr(Fruits, 0, nchar(Fruits)-1)
  # OR using regex 
  # aggstr = sub('\\s-.*', '', Fruits)
)]
result.dt <- dfs[,.(Avg = mean(Number) , Sd= sd(Number)), by="aggstr"]
```

EDIT: added standard deviation

Comment: I think your solution works perfectly for my toy-example but in my original problem - I often have data like "Box-86451-Apple" and then "Apple-Batch3246" so it may not work.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Okay added using regex wherein the pattern could be recognised for a string. Will be helpful for `data.table` newbies